# Data is not inserted through a form in MySQL (Coding is in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to insert data into mysql database through a form using php script.I am not getting any errors,bt the information  submitted by the form is not inserted into database..instead of the data(which is submitted by form),the values inserted in database are (1,1,1,1,1)..is this also an type of SQL injection attack?(as i searched on web nd got this attack name)
here's my php code for inserting data into database..

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clubcs.css">
<div class="text_field">
<div class="segment_header" align="center">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['first']));
$last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['last']));
$addr=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['addr']));
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['city']));
$contact=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['contact']));

$sql1=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO clubdata (FirstName, LastName, Address, City,Contact_no)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$sql1->bind_param("ssssi", $first, $last, $addr, $city, $contact);
$sql1->execute();

if(isset( $_POST["first"] ) &&  isset($_POST["last"]) && isset($_POST["addr"] ) && isset($_POST["city"]) &&  isset($_POST["contact"])  )
{
    echo "Thank You" ." " .$_POST["first"];
    echo " You have Successfully registered with us!";
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

is there something that i'm not getting or missing? Plz suggest me any solution!!

Comment: `$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['first']) ? $_POST['first'] : '');` & for all. not only `isset`

Comment: ...plus, `contact` is more than likely a string, so you'd want to use all `s`'s for your binds. `"sssss"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @fred and @Boren pointed out , you were passing in boolean integer values returned by isset.

If you move your `if(isset())` condition to wrap the whole code you won't have to check if the value are set again.

The truth is you didn't even need to escape anything, preparing the statement will do it for you.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["first"],$_POST["last"], $_POST["addr"],$_POST["city"],$_POST["contact"]))
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clubdata (FirstName, LastName, Address, City,Contact_no) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['first'], $_POST['last'], $_POST['addr'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['contact']);
    $stmt->execute();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
        echo "Thank You" ." " .$_POST["first"];
        echo " You have Successfully registered with us!";  
    }else{
        echo 'INSERT did not affect any rows';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Missing required fields";
    }

}
```

Oh and dont `exit` before closing your connection, you will leave it open.

Answer (score 2):

> *the values inserted in database are (1,1,1,1,1)*

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns just that, a `0` or a `1` which explains all the `1`'s returned, as `isset()` is assuming you want them all set, therefore returning  `TRUE` being `1`.

> Returns **TRUE** if `var` exists and has value other than **NULL, FALSE** otherwise.

You need to use a [**ternary operator**](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) with that also

```
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['first']) ? $_POST['first'] : '');
$last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['last']) ? $_POST['last'] : '');
$addr=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['addr']) ? $_POST['addr'] : '');
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '');
$contact=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['contact']) ? $_POST['contact'] : '');
```

---

***Sidenote:***

If "contact" is a string (*which stands to be*), you will want to use all `s`'s for your binds. I.e.: `"sssss"`

```
$sql1->bind_param("sssss", $first, $last, $addr, $city, $contact);
```

*An insight*.

Comment: bt contact is not a string..it's an integer type

Comment: @PujaJogi I had to make a note of it, *just in case*.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the isset() function returns 1 or 0 depending on whether the value is set or not. You need to do a check beforehand and then put the values in like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last']) && isset($_POST['addr']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['contact']))
{
  $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first']);
  $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last']);
  $addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['addr']);
  $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
  $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact']);
}
```

Comment: You're technically correct, however, [`this solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852533/data-is-not-inserted-through-a-form-in-mysql-coding-is-in-php#comment40451076_25852533) is what the OP intended on using, a ternary operator, which avoids (*and reduces*) in using mutliple `isset()` and/or `empty()` conditionals.